# Parse a txt file into multiple arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

Im trying to write a program that calculates grades, and wanna add a feature that allows it to read from a txt file. Im wondering how to iterate over the file and extract the information into separate arrays. An entry is as follows:

```
FINANCE

final at 50% [ 40 ]
homework at 25% [ 50 ]
quiz at 25% [ 100 ]
```

and I want to have six arrays:

```
[ FINANCE ] [ final homework quiz ] [ 50 25 25 ] [ 40 ] [50] [100].
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at JSON or CSV.

Comment: Can you provide additional information as to how the text file will be organized. Without this information, it is hard to help you.

Comment: Like @GaetanoRispoli said you need to post the organization of the document, but for any manual parsing read the file using `Scanner` and then just internally parse the strings into the arrays you want.